# C# NLua event handler with optional parameters

Tags: c#, events, lua

I want to register many events in lua wrapper, so I could access and do something within lua scripting. Like, for example I've got this:

```
addEventHandler('onEngineInit', function()
    print('Init')
end)

addEventHandler('onClientConnect', function(user)
    print(user)
end)
```

The first one event 'onEngineInit' doesn't have any parameters, but other one has some. I'm thinking that I could register these events with this 'addEventHandler' function.

So, in c# the could would look something like this:

```
public delegate void EventHandlerMethod(params object[] args);
public delegate void EngineInit();
public delegate void ClientConnect(string name);

private event EngineInit    onEngineInit;
private event ClientConnect onClientConnect;

void Init()
{
    lua.RegisterFunction("addEventHandler", this, GetType().GetMethod("AddEventHandler"));
    lua.DoFile("script.lua");
    OnEngineInit();

    // test
    OnClientConnect("player1");
}

public void AddEventHandler(string eventName, EventHandlerMethod eventHandler)
{
    if (eventName == "onEngineInit")
        onEngineInit = eventHandler;
    else if(eventName == "onClientConnect")
        onClientConnect = eventHandler;
}

public void OnEngineInit()
{
    onEngineInit?.Invoke();
}

public void OnClientConnect(string name)
{
    onClientConnect?.Invoke(name);
}
```

The point of this is to have a single function to register events in lua scripting. Is it possible to do something atleast similar?

Answer (score 1):

It is. You can use `RegisterLuaDelegateType` to register your delegate.

NLuaBox does this to register events handled on the Lua side: https://github.com/codefoco/NLuaBox/blob/master/Binder/NLuaBoxBinder.cs#L53

Use `object.EventName:Add (function() end)` to add the handler, like here: https://github.com/codefoco/NLuaBox/blob/master/Resources/source/ScriptListViewController.lua#L103